# Amazon Lambda writing to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to dynamoDB and I'm trying to write some data to the table using Lambda. 
So far I have this:

```
'AddFood': function () {

    var FoodName = this.event.request.intent.slots.FoodName.value;
    var FoodCalories = this.event.request.intent.slots.FoodCalories.value;
    console.log('FoodName : ' + FoodName);

    const params = {
        TableName: 'Foods',
        Item: {
            'id': {"S": 3},
            'calories': {"S": FoodCalories},
            'food': {"S": FoodName}
            }
    };

    writeDynamoItem(params, myResult=>{
        var say = '';

        say = myResult;

        say = FoodName + ' with ' + FoodCalories + ' calories has been added ';
        this.response.speak(say).listen('try again');
        this.emit(':responseReady');

    });

    function writeDynamoItem(params, callback) {

        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        AWS.config.update({region: AWSregion});

        var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB();

        console.log('writing item to DynamoDB table');

        docClient.putItem(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err, null)
            } else {
               callback(null, data)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the data is not appearing in the database? 
I have checked the IAM and the policy is set to AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess.

Comment: Generally, you should use get() or query() in preference to scan(), because a scan will read every item. Here is a JS example of calling putItem: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you have any idea why the code above isn't putting items into the database?

Comment: Does the putItem() call fail? How are you checking that the item was not written? Any chance you have the same-named table in multiple regions and are writing to the wrong one? PS your docClient is mis-named. The SDK has two interfaces (service interface and document client) - you're using the former but your variable is named as if you are using the latter.

Comment: I'm testing it on the amazon developer site by running the skill. I only have one table and I'm checking it by going into dynamoDB and viewing the items in the table. The call seems to be executing but nothing new shows up in the table. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: I've managed to fix it now. Thank for your help!

Comment: Care to share what the problem was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making a few changes to the write function, the following code allowed me to write items to the database:

function writeDynamoItem(params, callback) {

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: AWSregion});

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-1'});

console.log('writing item to DynamoDB table');

docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err, null)
         console.error("Unable to write item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
    } else {
       callback(null, data)
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To write to DynamoDB from a Lambda function (using Python)  you must use the `boto3` package and load the dynamodb resource:

Hope this helps, it is writing food and calories from the event and writing them with a generated uuid

```
import boto3
import os
import uuid

def writeToDynamo(event, context):

    recordId = str(uuid.uuid4())
    voice = event["food"]
    text = event["calories"]

    print('Generating new DynamoDB record, with ID: ' + recordId)
    print('Input food: ' + food)
    print('Input calories: ' + calories)

    #Creating new record in DynamoDB table
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['DB_TABLE_NAME'])
    table.put_item(
        Item={
            'id' : recordId,
            'food' : food,
            'calories' : calories
        }
    )

    return recordId
```

Comment: I know, I can help in python. Op wanted a function to write to dynamodb. He did not say anything about languages. You can combine functions in differente languages